# Celery task not excecuting with redis and fastapi

Tags: python, redis, celery, fastapi, celery-task

I am trying to make a task with celery using redis as broker and backend with fastapi.

I am new to this so I do not know what am I doing wrong.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcX_4EvYka4

I am also giving my own code below:

**.env**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://localhost:6379/0
```

**celery_worker.py**

```py
import os
import time

from celery import Celery
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND")


@celery.task(name="create_task")
def create_tasks(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
    time.sleep(a)
    return b + c
```

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body

# Initializes FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

from celery_worker import create_tasks
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse


@app.post("/test")
def run_task(data=Body(...)):
    amount = int(data["amount"])
    x = int(data["x"])
    y = int(data["y"])
    task = create_tasks.delay(amount, x, y)
    return JSONResponse({"Result": task.get()})
```

I am using `flower` to view the tasks in the browser.

When I am excecuting the `/test` endpoint a task is created. But it is not excecuting.

[image]

The command I am using to run celery and flower is below:

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=INFO
```

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery flower --port=5555
```

What could be the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following this answer it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824693/11348853

But I do not know why.

All I have to do is install eventlet

```
pip install eventlet
```

And then

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet
```

**N.B:** Same thing can be done by using `gevent`. Just replace `eventlet` with `gevent`.

Comment: Oh, are you running on Windows? If so, this is the reason it didn't work, Celery does not support Windows out of the box. But, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47331438/11612918) explains, you can get it to work using `eventlet` or `gevent`.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike FastAPI, you should only pass the module name on the command line, not the `Celery` object. So to start the worker, run

```
celery -A celery_worker worker --loglevel=INFO
```

Comment: Its the same problem. The task never excecutes.